# Ignore null parameters when serializing an object using FullSerializer in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I have an object I would like to serialize into json in Unity to send to a service via REST call. In .NET I know you can easily ignore null properties.

```
[JsonProperty("some_model", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class SomeModel
{
    ....
}
```

Is this possible using FullSerializer in Unity?

Currently I have

```
fsData data = null;
fsResult r = sm_Serializer.TrySerialize(objectToSerialize, out data);
string sendjson = data.ToString();
```

Is there a similar attribute I can add to the DataModel using FullSerializer?

```
[fsObject(ignoreNullProperties)]
public class SomeModel
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one answer is custom converters.

```
private static fsSerializer sm_Serializer = new fsSerializer();

[fsObject(Converter = typeof(CustomConverter))]
public class SomeClass
{
    string MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class CustomConverter : fsConverter
{
    private static fsSerializer sm_Serializer = new fsSerializer();

    public override bool CanProcess(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(SomeClass);
    }

    public override fsResult TryDeserialize(fsData data, ref object instance, Type storageType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override fsResult TrySerialize(object instance, out fsData serialized, Type storageType)
    {
        SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass)instance;
        serialized = null;

        Dictionary<string, fsData> serialization = new Dictionary<string, fsData>();

        fsData tempData = null;

        if (someClass.MyProp != null)
        {
            sm_Serializer.TrySerialize(someClass.MyProp, out tempData);
            serialization.Add("myProp", tempData);
        }

        serialized = new fsData(serialization);

        return fsResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This works but any other suggestions are greatly appreciated!